# Add one more attribute to JSON file

Tags: python, json, random

So I have a generated JSON which one looks like ( there is a lot of it just with unique ID )

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "dep": "dep",
    "Title": "Title',
    "email": "email"
}
```

I'm trying to do "append" a new field but I get an error

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(write_list, file)
file.close()

with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    entry = {'parentId': random.randrange(0, 487, 2)}
    json_file.append(entry, json_file)
json_file.close()
```

**It there is some way to add one more "key: value" to it after generating ?**

Comment: Please paste 3-5 lines of your JSON file here. It isn't clear what the structure is (JSON or JSON lines).

Comment: { "id": 3, "name": "name", "dep": "dep", "Title": "Title', "email": "email" }, { "id": 4, "name": "name", "dep": "dep", "Title": "Title', "email": "email" }, { "id": 5, "name": "name", "dep": "dep", "Title": "Title', "email": "email" }

Comment: @coldspeed added above, and I want to them all to looks like { "id": 3, "name": "name", "dep": "dep", "Title": "Title', "email": "email" , "parentId": "2"}

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. your are using `json.dump` to generate a list, but you're not using `json.load` to re-create the Python data structure.
2. You're opening the file with the `w` mode in the second open call, which truncates it

Try breaking each step out into its own and separating mutating data and writing to disk.

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(write_list, file)
#file.close()                     # manually closing files is unnecessary, 
                                  # when using context managers

with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
    write_list = json.load(json_file)
    entry = {'parentId': random.randrange(0, 487, 2)}
    write_list.append(entry)

with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(write_list, file)
```

Comment: yeah probably that's it, thnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

The steps to do what you want are as files:

3. Parse the entire JSON file into a python dictionary.
4. Add the entry to the dictionary.
5. Serialize the string back to JSON.
6. Write the JSON file back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Also after I done this feature with Tim McNamara advice,  I found a more pretty way to add new line to every JSON dict I have in file

```
for randomID in write_list:
    randomID['parentId'] = random.randrange(0, 487, 2)

with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(write_list, file)
```